# How to add a confirmation message for comments using both Django's built-in framework?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I want to create a simple message of "Your comment has been posted!" using Django's `messages` framework. I am using Django's `comments` framework and set it up so that after posting a comment it *refreshes* the page with

```
<div><input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" /></div>
```

inside my `form.html` that I created to override the `comments`'s default. I also had to include `django.core.context_processors.request` for `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` inside my `settings.py`.

Anyway, the [`messages` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/messages/#using-messages-in-views-and-templates) says to add messages inside `views.py`. Does that means I need to override the `comments`'s `views.py` or is there a simplier way to do this? I am a bit uncomfortable modifying the source code for `comments`. If I had to, I'm not even sure where to add the line

```
 messages.add_message( request, messages.SUCCESS, 'You comment has been posted!' )
```

under `def post_comment()` in `django.contrib.comments.views.comments`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [connect a custom receiver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) to [comment_was_posted signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/comments/signals/#django.contrib.comments.signals.comment_will_be_posted). It can look like this:

```
from django.contrib.comments.signals import comment_was_posted

def thank_user(sender, comment=None, request=None, **kwargs):
    messages.add_message( request, messages.SUCCESS, 'You comment has been posted!' )
comment_was_posted.connect(thank_user)
```

A nice place for such a snippet is a project_specific models.py, because they are all imported at model definition time.

Answer (score 3):

The secret is that when posting a comment the comments app sends a signal.  So set up a receiver to handle the comment_was_posted (or comment_will_by_posted) signal.  In the receiver call `messages.add_message(...)`

The docs for this are:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/comments/signals/#module-django.contrib.comments.signals

and

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals/